# Need javascript regex for amounts and decimals with percentage increases

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this expression so far, link to regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/OKHGzC/1/):

^[-+]?[0-9]\d{0,6}(.\d{1,3})?%?$

5 (valid)

5.5 (valid)

+5 (valid)

-6.999 (valid)

5% (valid but needs tweaking)

It works great except that I need to tweak it to accept a percentage at the end only if it starts with a plus or a minus, everything else is correct, so: 5% is invalid, +5% is valid, -5.5% is valid, +5 is valid (no percentage is required for +/-).

thanks.

Comment: Seems you have identical answers to choose from.  Here's a different one, `^(?=[-+].*%$|[-+]?.*[^%]$)[-+]?\d{1,6}(?:\.\d{1,3})?%?$` albeit slower.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to unwrap this pattern a bit and use alternation:

```
^(?:[-+]?\d{1,6}(?:\.\d{1,3})?|[-+]\d{1,6}(?:\.\d{1,3})?%)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k9zSOb/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A%5B-%2B%5D%3F%5Cd%7B1%2C6%7D(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D)%3F%7C%5B-%2B%5D%5Cd%7B1%2C6%7D(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D)%3F%25)%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of the non-capturing group to hold alternations

  - `[-+]?\d{1,6}(?:\.\d{1,3})?` - an optional `+` or `-`, 1 to 6 digits, and an optional sequence of `.` and 1 to 3 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `[-+]\d{1,6}(?:\.\d{1,3})?%` - a `+` or `-`, 1 to 6 digits, and an optional sequence of `.` and 1 to 3 digits and a `%` char
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.

In JS, you needn't repeat parts of the regex, you may build the pattern dynamically:

```js
var num_re = "\\d{1,6}(?:\\.\\d{1,3})?";
var regex = new RegExp("^(?:[-+]?" + num_re + "|[-+]" + num_re + "%)$");
var strs = ['5', '5.5', '+5', '-6.999', '5%', '+5%', '-5.5%'];
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", regex.test(s));
}
```

Output:

```
5 => true
5.5 => true
+5 => true
-6.999 => true
5% => false
+5% => true
-5.5% => true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^([-+]?\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,3})?|[-+]\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,3})?%)$
```

It takes ±123.12 (without percents) or 123.12% (with percents).

5% is invalid, 
+5% is valid,
-5% is valid